# Radio buttons behaving badly

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

So i've been coding that contact form for my website : [www.mangas-land.com/testingS/contact.html](http://www.mangas-land.com/testingS/contact.html), and there seems to be a problem with the radio buttons.

When i ran it on a laptop or desktop computer, it worked just fine, but once i had it ran on a tablet, Samsung for me, it started behaving weirdly. Only one radio button would float to the left, and the rest would stay to the extreme right and wouldn't position correctly.

I tried doing it with an absolute position but that's just not professional and isn't working accurately. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Please show your layout file

Comment: I'm no. on my computer right now, just on a friend's laptop. Can you please check the link out and hit F12, that should do it/

Comment: Is this even android related?

Comment: @SceLus In a way, yeah, since the only browser i'm having issues with is the Samsung Tab's one.